# Помогите разобратся с циклом в TelegramAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Вся задача кода это:

1. При активации команды (а именно /test) бот задаёт вопрос, и числовой ответ на вопрос он загоняет в переменную nitro.
2. Значение этой переменной бот должен использовать как кол-во повторов.
3. Бот выполняет код, и приходит к моменту когда нужно по ходу работы ответить на вопрос бота. НО. В момент когда бот задаёт вопрос, скрипт крашится. Если использую этот метод ввода данных вне цикла, то всё работает. Но стоит мне только попытаться запихнуть его в цикл. Так всё сразу крашится.
   Код:

```
def start(message):
    msgPrice = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько раз повторить программу?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice , Set_zap)
def Set_zap(messages):
    userPrice= messages.text
    nitro=messages.text
    nitro=int((nitro))
    while nitro!=0:
        print('Бим бам бам. Выполняю код.')
        print('Бим бам бам. Выполняю код.')
        msgPrice = bot.send_message(messages.chat.id, 'Сколько сейчас минут? (если на часах 11:37, то введи 37)')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice , Set_zapor)
        def Set_zapor(messages):
            userPrice= messages.text
            bot.send_message(messages.chat.id, f'Ну типа того чты: {messages.text}')
```

Comment: А вопрос какой?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как пофиксить

Answer (score 0):

у тебя бесконечный цикс, потому что переменная nitro не изменяется.

```
def start(message):
    msgPrice = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько раз повторить программу?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice , Set_zap)
def Set_zap(messages):
    userPrice= messages.text
    nitro=int(messages.text)
    while nitro!=0:
        print('Бим бам бам. Выполняю код.')
        print('Бим бам бам. Выполняю код.')
        msgPrice = bot.send_message(messages.chat.id, 'Сколько сейчас минут? (если на часах 11:37, то введи 37)')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice , Set_zapor)
        def Set_zapor(messages):
            userPrice= messages.text
            bot.send_message(messages.chat.id, f'Ну типа того чты: {messages.text}')
        nitro -= 1
```